# Redirect all pages of a parent page to another parent page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect subpages of a parent page to another parent page
like this:

```
/parent-1/sub-1  redirect to   /parent-2/sub-1
/parent-1/sub-2  redirect to   /parent-2/sub-2
/parent-1/sub-3  redirect to   /parent-2/sub-3
/parent-1/sub-4  redirect to   /parent-2/sub-4
```

and so on
i want to do these redirects without no plugin just using htaccess.( domain is not changed).
i know how to redirect a single page to another but there are over 150 pages
is there a way to redirect all pages

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post your tried sample htaccess rules file in your question, thank you.

Comment: Not sure why you actually mean by "i want to do these redirects without no plugin just using htaccess" ... Using any for of rewriting or redirection relies on plugins. Those directives are implemented in plugins, the apache http server follows a modular design principle, those modules are plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?parent-1/(.+)$ /parent-2/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That rule will redirect all "subpages". If you need to make exceptions, then an additional rule for those could be implement before, so above the `RewriteRule` in that sequence.

You can implement such such rules in the central http server's host configuration. Alternatively you can use a *distributed* configuration file (".htaccess"), if you have enabled the interpretation of such files for the http host and the location.

In general it is a good idea to start out using a `R=302` *temporary* redirection and to only change that to a `R=301` *permanent* redirection once everything works as desired. That prevents nasty caching issues on the client side. Also remember to always test using a fresh, anonymous browser window or to clear your browsers cache.